# Bundles over bundles

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, differential-topology, vector-bundles, fiber-bundles

Are there interesting examples of bundles over bundles (for example the tangent bundle of the tangent bundle of a manifold)?  How can they be used?  Are there any interesting relevant formulas or invariants?

Comment: In the vector bundle scenerio, does this just amount to the Whitney sum?

Comment: I think your question is too broad to really find a good answer. Maybe you want to be more specific about some particular ideas or contexts.

Comment: Bundles over bundles, with no further explanation, can be thought of as two different things..   One, we have a vector bundle $E\rightarrow B$ and a vector bundle $E'\rightarrow E$... I have no hope that this would be interesting... Second possible explanation of bundles over bundles is I have a vector bundle $E\rightarrow B$ and another vector bundle $E'\rightarrow B'$ with a morphism of vector bundles $(E,B)\rightarrow (E',B')$... This is what I think is a good notion of bundle over bundle...

Comment: Just like manifold over manifold mean a pair of manifolds with a map between them, bundles over bundles would be a pair of bundles with a morphism between them... Studying this morphism of bundles  might say something about both the bundles... Is this what you are thinking of?

Comment: There is a similar sounding notion of “fibration over a fibration” where you extend the last map so “up to homotopy” it is the inclusion of the fiber of a fibration. A fibration that has this extension property is a principal fibration.

Comment: Let B be our base manifold of a bundle with fiber F and total space E.  If we forget the bundle structure and treat E as a topological space, then let E = B' be the base for some new bundle with total space E' and fiber F'.

I'm hoping that this scenario simplifies to Koushik's statement.

Comment: @Koushik Now I see that my question was the first situation in your first comment.  Doesn't this reduce to the second situation?  We have vector bundles (E, B) and (E', B'), with B' isomorphic to E (perhaps special attention needs to be paid to basepoints?).

So, in this situation, We have a bundle E -> B, and another bundle E' -> E.  Does there exist a bundle morphism (E,B) -> (E',B')?  Or perhaps a morphism in the other direction (E', B') -> (E, B).

When I try to visualize the local trivializations, I keep picturing the sum of the vector space fibers.

Comment: The cotangent bundle is always a symplectic manifold. The symplectic form eats tangent vectors of the cotangent bundle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some Lie groups are. For example $SO(n)$ is interesting. It is a sphere bundle over a sphere bundle over a sphere bundle...

Namely you can think of $SO(n)$ as being $n$ orthonormal vectors in $\mathbb R^n$. I.e. $A\in SO(n)$ can be seen as an $n$ tuple $A=(v_1,\ldots, v_n)$. Then mapping $A$ to $v_1$ defines a map $SO(n)\rightarrow S^{n-1}$. What is the fiber? Well, these consist of an orthonormal basis of the plane orthogonal to the subspace spanned by $v_1$. Hence the fiber can be identified with $SO(n-1)$. By induction we see that $SO(n)$ is an iterated sphere bundle.

Comment: So would these iterated bundles be described by flags and morphisms then?  "Flag bundles"?  I will try to make this more precise...

Comment: I don't think these are exactly flag manifolds. But flag manifolds are a good example of iterated fiber bundles.

Comment: We have a filtration of subroups O(k) acting on the k-dimension part of the flag, Rk.  So O(n) (implicitly with this filtration of subgroups) acts on the flag associated with Rn.  We also have that, for each k, O(k) is the direct limit of all of the smaller O(j)'s.
<br><br>

Is this best described as a "filtered fibration"?  In the structure of Lie groups, I know we benefit from looking at parabolic subgroups and flags.  I don't seem to find anything about groups acting on the more general iterated bundles.  Perhaps this requires a new thread.

Comment: Flag manifolds, along with being bundles over bundles, also have different possible projection maps. The space of $k$-planes inside $\ell$-planes (through the origin) in $\Bbb C^n$ projects to both Grassmannians $G(k,n)$ and $G(\ell,n)$.